# SugarCRM Rest api function response always trimmed by last 2 characters

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have the issue in the SugarCRM REST Function. I have created the Sugar Module I am working in that. I have dashlet file for a REST call and in that, there is the function, So from that function whatever I return, That response always truncates the last 2 characters.

Initially I was thinking this is the issue from REST API, but for now I hardcoded the response but still, the issues are there.

Suppose I return "Hello World", Then I am getting the response "Hello Wor"

```
<?php

require_once('include/api/SugarApi.php');
require_once 'include/SugarTheme/SidecarTheme.php';
require_once('custom/clients/base/helper/SecurityHelper.php');
class FreshDashletApi extends SugarApi
{
    public function registerApiRest()
    {
        return array(
            'freshdeskdashlet' => array(
                'reqType' => 'GET',
                'path' => array('freshdeskdashlet'),
                'pathVars' => array(''),
                'method' => 'getFreshdeskDashlet',
                'shortHelp' => '',
                'longHelp' => '',
            ),
            'ticketfields' => array(
                'reqType' => 'GET',
                'path' => array('ticketfields'),
                'pathVars' => array(''),
                'method' => 'getCustomFields',
                'shortHelp' => '',
                'longHelp' => '',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getFreshdeskDashlet($api, $args)
    {
        $data = array (
            'ticket_json' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'associates_rdb' => NULL,
                            'association_type' => NULL,
                            'cc_email' =>
                                array (
                                    'cc_emails' =>
                                        array (
                                        ),
                                    'fwd_emails' =>
                                        array (
                                        ),
                                    'reply_cc' =>
                                        array (
                                        ),
                                    'tkt_cc' =>
                                        array (
                                        ),
                                ),
                            'created_at' => '2019-02-05T15:06:30+05:30',
                            'deleted' => false,
                            'delta' => true,
                            'description' => 'This is our test ticket for Sugar CRM Test',
                            'description_html' => '
This is our test ticket for Sugar CRM Test
',
                            'dirty' => 0,
                            'display_id' => 22,
                            'due_by' => '2019-02-08T15:06:30+05:30',
                            'email_config_id' => NULL,
                            'frDueBy' => '2019-02-06T15:06:30+05:30',
                            'fr_escalated' => false,
                            'group_id' => NULL,
                            'id' => 42017573142,
                            'internal_agent_id' => NULL,
                            'internal_group_id' => NULL,
                            'isescalated' => false,
                            'owner_id' => NULL,
                            'parent_ticket_id' => NULL,
                            'priority' => 1,
                            'requester_id' => 42008575970,
                            'responder_id' => NULL,
                            'sl_escalation_level' => NULL,
                            'sl_manual_dueby' => NULL,
                            'sl_merge_parent_ticket' => NULL,
                            'sl_product_id' => NULL,
                            'sl_skill_id' => NULL,
                            'sl_sla_policy_id' => NULL,
                            'sla_state' => 0,
                            'source' => 3,
                            'spam' => false,
                            'st_survey_rating' => NULL,
                            'status' => 2,
                            'subject' => 'Sugar Test',
                            'ticket_type' => 'Question',
                            'to_email' => NULL,
                            'trained' => false,
                            'updated_at' => '2019-02-05T15:06:30+05:30',
                            'urgent' => false,
                            'status_name' => 'Open',
                            'requester_status_name' => 'Being Processed',
                            'priority_name' => 'Low',
                            'source_name' => 'Phone',
                            'requester_name' => 'Amol Rokade',
                            'responder_name' => 'No Agent',
                            'to_emails' => NULL,
                            'product_id' => NULL,
                            'custom_field' =>
                                array (
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
            'domain' => 'abc.pqr.com',
            'credentials' => 'X2Y9CfvfdvseUUZvdfvfdvvfvf7e3Pud1tI',
            'ssl' => 'http',
            'ticket_fields' =>
                array (
                    'ticket_fields' =>
                        array (
                            'ticket_type' =>
                                array (
                                    'Question' => 'Question',
                                    'Incident' => 'Incident',
                                    'Problem' => 'Problem',
                                    'Feature Request' => 'Feature Request',
                                ),
                            'ticket_status' =>
                                array (
                                    'Open' => 2,
                                    'Pending' => 3,
                                    'Resolved' => 4,
                                    'Closed' => 5,
                                    'Waiting on Customer' => 6,
                                    'Waiting on Third Party' => 7,
                                ),
                            'ticket_priority' =>
                                array (
                                    'Low' => 1,
                                    'Medium' => 2,
                                    'High' => 3,
                                    'Urgent' => 4,
                                ),
                            'ticket_group' =>
                                array (
                                    'Product Management' => 42000076370,
                                    'QA' => 42000076371,
                                    'Sales' => 42000076372,
                                ),
                            'agent' =>
                                array (
                                    'John Deo' => 42001642325,
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
            'email' => 'John@gmail.co.in',
            'tickets' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'ticket_field' =>
                                array (
                                    'active' => true,
                                    'column_name' => NULL,
                                    'created_at' => '2018-05-02T10:07:06+05:30',
                                    'default' => true,
                                    'description' => 'Ticket status',
                                    'editable_in_portal' => false,
                                    'field_options' => NULL,
                                    'field_type' => 'default_status',
                                    'flexifield_coltype' => NULL,
                                    'flexifield_def_entry_id' => NULL,
                                    'id' => 42000265137,
                                    'import_id' => NULL,
                                    'label' => 'Status',
                                    'label_in_portal' => 'Status',
                                    'level' => NULL,
                                    'name' => 'status',
                                    'parent_id' => NULL,
                                    'position' => 4,
                                    'prefered_ff_col' => NULL,
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'required_for_closure' => false,
                                    'required_in_portal' => false,
                                    'ticket_form_id' => 42000023745,
                                    'updated_at' => '2018-05-02T10:07:06+05:30',
                                    'visible_in_portal' => true,
                                    'choices' =>
                                        array (
                                            0 => 'Open',
                                            1 => 'Pending',
                                            2 => 'Resolved',
                                            3 => 'Closed',
                                            4 => 'Waiting on Customer',
                                            5 => 'Waiting on Third Party',
                                        ),
                                    'nested_ticket_fields' =>
                                        array (
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
            'module' => 'Contact',
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In The console, I am getting below error.

```
HttpError {request: HttpRequest, status: 200, responseText: "↵↵{"ticket_json":[{"associates_rdb":null,"associat…"],"nested_ticket_fields":[]}}],"module":"Contact", textStatus: "parsererror", errorThrown:
```

But unfortunietly, I unable to find the from where its exactely doing the JSON Parse and why only last 2 charachers are get Truncated.

Any Help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have fixed the issue at my own.
>
> > The issue was the PHP file encoded wrong.
> >
> > The old files were saved as UTF8 with BOM, but I changed to UTF-8 and its working fine now.
> >
> > BOM consists of some extra chars before the content of the file and also used ob_clean  before sending the response.